# Generate solid colors using CSS linear-gradient (not smooth colors)

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

Assuming my linear CSS gradient looks like this:

`background: linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, green 20%, blue 40%, purple 60%, yellow 80%, black 100%)`

It will generate a CSS gradient that looks like this:

[image]

How do I make the same gradient but with solid colors without the transitioning between the colors? (using CSS)

Something similar to this:

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Like this

```css
.gradient {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, 
      red    20%, 
      green  20%, 
      green  40%, 
      blue   40%, 
      blue   60%, 
      purple 60%, 
      purple 80%, 
      yellow 80%,
      yellow 100%
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

Answer (score 12):

Gradient is created through the blending of colors. **You can control the blending effect of colors by specifying range for each color** like in below example of `.flag`:

- the color `#00ae00` will be applied till `33.3%` of the `div`.
- from that point till `66.6%`, `white` will be applied.
- in the end `orange` will start from `66.6%` till the end of the box.

**This way you can add as many colors as you want.**

But one thing keep in mind, it looks fine when the degree is straight, if you change the angle, in some cases edges of colors may not look smooth (depends upon color and screen density) as you can see in `.pixeleted`

```css
.flag{
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #00ae00 33.3%, white 33.3%, white 66.6%, orange 66.6%);

}

.pixeleted{
    background: linear-gradient(30deg, red 33.3%, black 33.3%, black 66.6%, red 66.6%);
}
    
div {
  width: 290px;
  height: 145px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flag"></div>
<div class="pixeleted"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't have to repeat the colors. It's also possible to write it like this:

```css
background: linear-gradient(to right, 
      red    20%, 
      green  0 40%,
      blue   0 60%,
      purple 0 80%,
      yellow 0 100%
  );
```